# Get derived object from base class object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am programming a grammar parser for learning purposes and I have problems with inheritance.

```
var grammars = new Grammar[] { new VariableGrammar() };
this.GrammarRules = new List<Grammar>(grammars);
```

I create a list of `Grammar`'s, `VariableGrammar` inherits from `Grammar`. But in later coding stages there would be many more objects in the list of different types, all of which inherit from `Grammar`. When I want to access an element I could use a `foreach` like this:

```
var grammars = new Grammar[] { new VariableGrammar() };
this.GrammarRules = new List<Grammar>(grammars);

foreach (var grammarRule in this.GrammarRules)
{
    grammarRule.Parse("...");
}
```

But the problem is that `grammarRule` is `Grammar` and not a `VariableGrammar`. Because of that the `Parse` method of the `Grammar` class is called instead of the `VariableGrammar` class.

The question is:
**Is there a possibility to access the original object with the right Type in this case** `VariableGrammar`**?**

I know there is the possibility of casting it, but then I have to write a big code block for every possible cast option. 
Another possibility could be using reflection and call the method over this approach but this is not that great either because when I change the method name I have to change it in the reflection too, because I am only able to call the method via the method name as a `string`.

Comment: hint: have a look at `virtual`/`abstract` methods

Comment: additional remark: I think you are talking about **reflection** and no I would not consider that an option here ;)

Comment: @Carsten yes i meant reflection :) and your tips was very helpful too -- thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem is that `grammarRule` is `Grammar` and not an `VariableGrammar`.

Actually, it is both, because `VariableGrammar` derives from `Grammar`

> Because of that the `Parse` method of the `Grammar` class is called instead of the `VariableGrammar` class.

This means that the `Parse` method in the `Grammar` class is *not* marked [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx). Once you mark it `virtual` and add `override` to the implementation in `VariableGrammar`, the problem will be solved.